# Why "bench" for judges?

Tags: word-choice

Why is the word "bench" used specifically to describe a judge or the judicial process?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bench_%28law%29) answers your question.

> The historical roots of that meaning come from the fact that judges formerly sat on long seats or benches (freestanding or against a wall) when presiding over a court.

Answer (score 0):

The bench a part of the judge's courtroom, specifically the chair on which the judge sits.

It is a [synecdoche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche) in which the part (a bench) represents the whole (the judge, and by extension, his or her rulings). (Please don't downvote if you think it's *metonymy*; you're probably right!)

Some metaphors using "bench":

- Legislate from the bench (a judge usurps the role of legislators through a ruling) (see comment from @TimLymington)
- A sitting judge (seated on that once-removed bench and able to hear cases)
- Before the full bench (*en banc*, when judges of a certain court sit together); see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bench_%28law%29
- [Bench trial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bench_trial) (a trial is before a judge (as opposed to a jury))
- Bench and bar (judges and lawyers)

Comment: I realize it is the chair on which the judge sits, but why do we use "bench" rather than "chair" for the judiciary? The answer seems to be that a bench being long seats several people. This aspect of the judiciary seems to distinguish it from the other branches of goverment where individual seats are generally provided. This is what @Tim pointed out at the other page.

Comment: OK, you are interested in the etymology, not the metaphor. It's a "bench" for historical reasons. Here's the second sentence from the Bench (law) article cited above: "The historical roots of that meaning come from the fact that judges formerly sat on long seats or benches." Also, see the "full bench" metaphor; there was a point in time when many judges would sit on one bench.

Comment: I can think of two other etymological parallels (which also involve synecdoche). 1) The Pope sometimes speaks *ex cathedra*, lit. "from the chair." 2) Roman banking houses used a long bench, a *banca*, for transactions, evolving into our words bank (evolving from *banca* to French *banque*) and bankrupt (lit. "broken bench"). These ancient words of "chair" and "bench" take on new meanings through association with who is seated in the chair or whether the bench is broken or not.

Comment: your comment on Roman banking connects well with the answer by Tim at the other question, where he claims that the "bench" in question is actually the table rather than the seating arrangement.  I don't know why your comment got voted down, it seems fine to me.

Comment: Thank you, @katz, for your comment. The downvoter may have been very particular about metonymy vs. synechdoche. But there's no accounting for taste.

Comment: Last semester, I wrote a research paper about sovereign default (=nations going bankrupt), where I first encountered the etymologies of "bank" and "bankrupt." The "bench" for a courtroom and the "bench" for a bank did not evolve along a single path, but the parallel mental process is fascinating.